# Javascript redirecting on everypage can't remove

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file that was accidentally added to the admin side of our site. The javascript is below,

```
<script>
if (document.getElementById("errorTitle") != null && document.getElementById("errorTitle").innerHTML === "Insufficient Privileges") {
  window.location.replace("/portal/InsufficientPrivileges");
} else {
  window.location.replace("/portal/FileNotFound");
}
</script>
```

The problem is that this code runs on the admin pages so we are unable to remove it. If we disable javascript on the browser the page never renders, dynamic content. How can we disable this from running so we can upload the proper file?

Comment: Aint you are able to edit files? I mean that you dont need to open file as a webpage to edit it

Comment: How did this get "accidentally added"?  Why can't you remove it?

Comment: Both of these choices seem to go to error states.  I'm guessing that you went to the page because of a prior error.  I'd fix the problem on the prior page.

Comment: No, the way this platform works is that its a black box. We upload the file and assign where we want it. Since the file is considered "in use" there is no way for us to override it until it is removed from the admin menu.

Comment: Use the debugger to edit the DOM

Comment: If it's an open-source or off-the-shelf package, then tell us the name of it and we might be able to help. Otherwise ask the vendor, or the sysadmin who installed it for you.

Comment: @Hogan The problem is that this javascript file is being added to everypage and not just the handful that we were expecting due to a platform update this weekend. Since it ends in an `else` every page is redirected.

Comment: Open the page and spam esc until you are able to be on the page to open your console and view the sources tab. Open the folder for your site(in the sources tab) and find the javascript that is causing the problem and add a breakpoint before it. Refresh the page, then edit the code before progressing past the breakpoint.

Comment: @KevinB I have added the breakpoint and am able to get it to stop but I do not see any option to edit the code. I can go to the elements tab (in chrome) and am able to delete it but on the sources tab it keeps the code. Any thoughts on how to edit the code?

Comment: After you edit the code, save(ctrl+s), and then click the continue button and it will continue past the breakpoint and execute the modified code.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the help but when I do a ctrl+s it opens the windows save local box instead of committing the edit. Any idea how to make the main file, home.jsp, file read the changes?

Comment: no, you can't change the jsp from the browser. you can only change the local copy of the html/javascript that is currently in the browser. When i press ctrl+s it saves the code i'm editing and recompiles it within the console. I'm also using the popout console, not the one connected to the browser, so that may be why you're seeing a different save dialog.

Comment: Make sure you are doing your editing in the sources tab, not the elements tab.

Comment: You can try pressing `Esc` on your keyboard as soon as you see the page loading the new page... But if it's too fast then there's not much you can do. I guess try pressing `Backspace` and `Esc` to go back a page each time it redirects you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to edit the page that contains the reference to the problem file.  If you can just edit the page to jump over where that code is called with an if statement or goto.

If you can't edit the other pages then you can Use the debugger to change the code executed on the fly.  Chrome and Firefox have debuggers that should be able to do this.

Specifically for Chrome you go into the object inspector (available via menus or right clicking on the page).  Then you can see the HTML on the left window.  You select the script tag of interest, you can right click and select delete or select "Edit HTML"

Comment: Can you explain or provide some information on how to edit the code on the fly? I am currently using Chrome but I can use FF if it works better.

Comment: I have added the breakpoint and am able to get it to stop but I do not see any option to edit the code. I can go to the elements tab (in chrome) and am able to delete it but on the sources tab it keeps the code. Any thoughts on how to edit the code so that it will actually prevent from running?

Comment: You can't change the source that is on the server.  If you can't breakpoint before the problem happens you might need to write an extension to do it for you.

Comment: @aDroidman if it's in a script tag you could remove this script tag in the Elements tab

Answer (score 0):

If the page redirects you before you're even able to edit anything, you can use automated tools.

#### Fiddler (Windows)

Fiddler lets you see all pages downloaded, and then you can have it send your browser a different page when it tries downloading any page you specify (AutoResponder feature). This way you can temporarily *edit* a page while you can fix it in the admin panel.

#### Greasemonkey (Firefox) or Tampermonkey (Chrome)

These plugins let you run JavaScript code on a page as soon as it gets to your browser. This will let you do things such as removing the script tag programmatically.